# Router wifi suddenly looses connection

Tags: router

I am having TpLink Archer 20 router. I have 1 laptop and 1 mobile connected to 2.5ghz, and 1 amazon firestick connected to 5ghz. At some point, all the devices lose connection. My mobile will fall back to mobile data. The laptop and firestick will say its connected, no internet. I won't be even able to open the router config page. The wifi light for 2.5 and 5 is ON and internet light is also ON in router. When I restart the router everything goes back to normal. This happens twice or thrice a day. I have switched to the less-used channel, but still, the issue is there. I am not sure which device is creating the problem. Is it the router or firestick or mobile/laptop

2.5 GHz : Channel3, Channel Width = Auto

5 GHz : Channel36, Channel Width = Auto

Used Wifi Analyzer app to set the best channel.

Comment: While @John's answer below will likely resolve the issue, a factory reset is generally the last option after troubleshooting has failed _(due to the inconvenience of re-setting up a router)_. What channels are your 2.4GHz _(1 - 11)_ and 5GHz _(should be set to highest possible channel, and if in the US, try 157)_ networks using, and at what channel width (20MHz, 40Mhz, 80MHz, or 160MHz).  Have you used WireShark to determine if you're overlapping with a neighbor's router (which could cause the disconnect due to interference)? Does it only happen at certain times/when certain appliances are on?

Comment: It is happening at random, other than TV and mobile/laptop chargers I dont have any appliance in the room.

Comment: I would create a backup of your config on your router's WebUI, then do what @John suggested.  I would also analyze the WiFi networks around you via WireShark either before or after doing what John suggested in his answer

Comment: do I need to use wireshark? I already tried using wifi analyzer, found that channel 3 and channel 36 is better

Comment: Channel 36 should not be used for 5GHz networks... as I mentioned, 5GHz should be set to the _**highest**_ possible channel your country allows, otherwise you lose performance.

Answer (score 1):

From your description above, the router is the issue (apparently not your devices).  Go to the Support site for the router, download the most recent firmware for your router, update the firmware, then do a hard reset of the router and set it up again. Reliability should improve